# Reverse words(not letters) for a string without using .reverse()

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The problem I am working on asks for me to write a function `reverseMessage()` that takes a string message and reverses the order of the words in place.

The answer I first came up with works but apparently doesn't meet the [requirements](https://www.interviewcake.com/question/reverse-words) of this task:

```
function reverseMessage(string) {
    return string.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}
```

For example:

```
var string = "reversed are string your in words the now"
var results = "now the words in your string are reversed"
```

New solution:

I would like to split this string into an array and then loop through that array and swap the 1st index with the last index, the 2nd index with second to last index, 3rd index with the 3rd to last index, etc... until I meet in the middle.

I am trying to make the two different functions below work:

```
 function reverseMessage(string) {
     var array = string.split(" ");
     //loop through array and replace first index with last index, second   
     index with second to last index, third index with third to last index, etc
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length/2; i++) {
         for (var j = (array.length-1); j > array.length/2; j--) {
             array[i] = array[j];
             array[j] = array[i];
             messageSplit.join(",");
     }
 };



 function reverseMessage2(string) {
     var array = string.split(" ");
     var newArray = []
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length/2; i++) {
         newArray.unshift(array[i]++);
         newArray.join(",");
         return newArray;
     }
 };
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: `array[i] = array[j]; array[j] = array[i];` isn't going to "work" because you just replaced `array[i]` with `array[j]`!

Comment: Yeah I figured- just not sure how to write it correctly- thought I would write down somewhat of an idea of what I would like to happen hoping others could see what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in yours reverseMessage function You are trying to swap variable for that you are doing

array[i] = array[j]; 
array[j] = array[i];

Which is giving array[i]=array[j] so let say array[i]="This" and array[j]="That"so according to yours code array[i] will be "That" and array[j] will also be "That" so you can try something like this:

```
 function reverseMessage(string) {
     var array = string.split(" ");
     //loop through array and replace first index with last index, second
     //index with second to last index, third index with third to last index, etc
     for (var i = 0,j=(array.length)-1; i < array.length/2; i++) {
             temp=array[i]
             array[i] = array[j];
             array[j]=array[i]
             array[j] = temp; j--;}
       console.log(array.join(" "));
 };  reverseMessage("find you will pain only go you recordings security the into if");
```

Comment: I tried to put in a larger string and it didn't work like it did for the shorter string. example --------var message = 'find you will pain only go you recordings security the into if' ----------- results = 'recordings security the into if find you you will pain only go' ------------- when it should be = 'if into the security recordings you go only pain will you find'

Comment: @xgrioux Check now this one will help you

Answer (score 4):

```
   function reverseMessage(string) {
     var array = string.split(" ");
     var result="";
     for (var i = array.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
         result+=array[i]+" ";
     }
    console.log(result);
 };
```

Comment: wow that was a lot simpler then what I was trying to do lol- thanks psylogic

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
function reverseMessage( str ) {

    var arrStr = [];
    var temp ="";
    for(var i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] === " ")
        {
            arrStr.push(temp);
            temp="";
        }
        else
        {
            temp += str[i]; 
        }
    }
    if(temp.length >= 0)
    {
        arrStr.push(temp);
    }
    var result = "";
    for(var x=arrStr.length-1 ; x >=0 ; x--)
    {
        result += " "+arrStr[x];
    }
    return result;
}


console.log(reverseMessage("I am here"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, someone's gotta do it:

```js
function rev(s){
  var a = s.split(/ /),
      l = a.length;
      i = l/2 | 0;
  while (i--) a.splice(i, 1, a.splice(l-1-i, 1, a[i])[0]);
  return a.join(' ');
}

    document.write(rev('0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.split()`, `Array.pop()`, `Array.push()` and `String.substr()`:

```js
var flip = function(str) {
  var res = "", sp = " ",  arr = str.split(sp);
  while (arr.length)
    res += arr.pop() + sp;
  return res.substr(0, res.length - 1); //remove last space
};
alert(flip("reversed are string your in words the now"));
```

Using `String.lastIndexOf()` and `String.substr()`:

```js
var flip = function(str) {
  var res = "", i, sp = ' ';
  while (str) {
    i = str.lastIndexOf(sp);
    res += str.substr(i + 1) + sp;
    str = str.substr(0, i);
  }
  return res.substr(0, res.length - 1); //remove last space
};

alert(flip("reversed are string your in words the now"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is split the words message into individual strings reverse them and then add them together, that will reverse them in place. Try

```
function reverseMessage(message){
  var reversedMessage = ''; //A string to hold the reversed message
  var words = message.split(' ');
  for(var i =0; i< words.length; i++){
     reversedMessage +=  reverse(words[i]) + " ";// add the reversed word to the reversed message, with a space at the end so the words dont touch
  }
  return reversedMessage
}
//A helper function that reverses a string
function reverse(s) {
  var o = '';
  for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    o += s[i];
  return o;
}
```

sources: http://eddmann.com/posts/ten-ways-to-reverse-a-string-in-javascript/

Comment: This is helpful when reversing everything in the string. I was trying to just reverse the words. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: The words would reverse yes but the letters of the words would not. So if my string before = 'find you will pain only go you recordings security the into if' then the after would be= 'if into the security recordings you go only pain will you find' -----Your solution's after looks like this= "dnif uoy lliw niap ylno og uoy sgnidrocer ytiruces eht otni fi "

Answer (score 0):

```
with `pop()` ;)

function reverseMessage(string) {
         var array = string.split(" ");
         var result="";
         while (array.length > 0) {
             result += array.pop()+" ";
         }
        console.log(result);
     };
```

Comment: Your solution keeps crashing my server :(

Comment: oopsie, my mistake. test now :)

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.